# Lua std::map bind does not work

Tags: lua

I want to construct a c++ std map in Lua like this:

```
> TWAP { "enable" = 1, "interval" = 120, "pershares" = 2500 }
```

However, here is the error:

```
> cannot run config file:
> /home/tzhang/luatest/alphaless/strategy_config.lua:43: '}' expected
> near '='
```

How can I modify it?

Comment: Most probably `TWAP { enable = 1, interval = 120, pershares = 2500 }`.

Comment: thank u, is it useful for map<string, int>?

Comment: You are constructing a Lua table.  How is this related to `std::map` in C++?

Comment: May be, you want this: `TWAP = { enable = 1, interval = 120, pershares = 2500 }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of these two syntax flavours:

```
TWAP { enable = 1, interval = 120, pershares = 2500 }
```

or

```
TWAP { ["enable"] = 1, ["interval"] = 120, ["pershares"] = 2500 }
```

The second one allows you to use *values* of variables, if used without quotes:

```
local foo = "bar"
local tbl = { [foo] = 42 } -- creates a pair with 'bar' key and 42 value
```

Comment: thank u !! but when I test these 2 ways, the error becomes to[ cannot run config file: /home/tzhang/luatest/alphaless/strategy_config.lua:43: attempt to call global 'TWAP' (a nil value)  ],    and the map I want to construct is map<string,int>

Comment: In this case, it seems like your script is quite broken, and we'll need more info in the original question. Consider taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link.